# Plone 4.0.5 and Unicode confusion

Tags: unicode, utf-8, plone

At first, Im using FreeBSD 8.1, Plone 4.0.5 and testing both Data.fs and RelStorage 1.5.0b2 (Postgresql 9.0.3). Im from Denmark and we use danish letters ("æøå").

Im confused about encoding, but my initial guess is that the best way to go is with Unicode (utf-8). What is the correct way to configure FreeBSD, Plone (and products) and PostgreSQL to comply with Danish letters. Ive already been told that the encoding does not matter for PostgreSQL.

Ive been seeing comments about site.py and sitecustomize.py around when googling for errors - please comment.

Thanks.
Nikolaj G.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plone and all its add-ons support Unicode by default, you don't need to configure the encoding at any level.

Even when using RelStorage, we only store binary data inside the SQL database and no strings, so there's no de/encoding taking place at this level.

Changing the Python default encoding in site.py or sitecustomize.py is actually harmful and you *should not* do this. It will only mask actual programming errors inside the code base and can lead to inconsistent data.

Inside the codebase we do use a mixture of both Unicode and utf-8 encoded strings. So generally your code will have to be written in a way to handle both of these. This is unfortunate but a side-effect of us slowly migrating to proper Unicode at all levels.

Comment: Thanks Hanno, so it does not matter if Im using ISO8859-1 or UTF-8 for the OS encoding (LC_CTYPE etc. in .cshrc). Is that correct understood? I guess all locale (language) configuration is done when choosing language during site creation, correct?I wont use site.py and

Comment: (sorry, hit enter) ... and sitecustomzie.py. Thanks. Nikolaj G.

Comment: We don't rely on any OS level locale settings. As a web application we need to be able to deliver every response in a potentially different locale, depending on a number of variables. So all locale related settings are done inside the application - but for a monolingual site the language is the only one that matters.

Comment: Thanks Hanno, I get the first part, but what do you do you mean with "but for a monolingual site the language is the only one that matters". They way I understand what you're writing: no matter if the site is multi -or monolangual, it does not matter which OS locale is used, correct? PS with locale I mean e.g. LC_CTYPE=da_DK.UTF-8. Thanks. Nikolaj G.

Comment: Cool. Thank Geir. Ive runned so many tests - Im convinced now ;-) have a nice day. Nikolaj G.